# How exactly did Obi Wan Kenobi alter the hidden message to the remaining Jedi who were alive?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, obi-wan-kenobi

After the Order 66 execution we see Obi Wan Kenobi and Master Joda in the Jedi Temple. In the next scene we observe Master Kenobi trying to alter the hidden message to all the remaining Jedi. He tried to do so by (using the Force I guess) waving his hand upon the Jedi Temple's Archives data storage unit.

How is a database supposed to work with the Force, and how without using a computer was he able to alter the hidden message from the database?

In conclusion, **how exactly did Obi Wan Kenobi alter the hidden message to the remaining Jedi who were alive?**

Comment: "Master Joda"...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The film's official novelisation indicates that he used the Force

> In the main holocomm center of the Jedi Temple, high atop the central
> spire, **Obi-Wan used the Force to reach deep within the shell of the
> recall beacon’s mechanism, subtly altering the pulse calibration to
> flip the signal from come home to run and hide.** Done without any
> visible alteration, it would take the troopers quite a while to detect
> the recalibration, and longer still to reset it. This was all that
> could be done for any surviving Jedi: a warning, to give them a
> fighting chance.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

The [junior novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization)) also implies that he added some extra safeguards to prevent its detection.

> Still, avoiding the clones took time. It was full night by the time
> they reached the main control center. Yoda stood guard while Obi-Wan
> reset the beacon and then added a few twists to hide what he had done.
> When Yoda gave him an impatient look, Obi-Wan explained, “I’ve
> recalibrated the code to warn any surviving Jedi away.” That was much
> better than simply disabling the beacon.

However, we learn in Star Wars: Rebels that he found time to get a longer, visual and audio message to fleeing Jedi. It's not [entirely clear](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89514/how-does-obi-wan-find-out-about-the-empire-in-time-to-mention-it-in-his-warning?lq=1) whether this was included in the beacon message or somehow sent subsequently.

Comment: oh man, i was really expecting a much more serious result than that, even for the SW universe....i dont understand how exactly he means that he recalibrated, because as it is explained i understand of it like being a switch, go home up, run awway down, or something close to that, or else the other explanation would be that he actually changed bits of data with the Force....

Comment: Note that this is incompatible with current Disney canon. Obi-Wan sends out a much longer, verbal message, according to Rebels and related material, so unless he used the Force to generate an entire hologram recording, this detail is likely no longer canon. See: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89514/how-does-obi-wan-find-out-about-the-empire-in-time-to-mention-it-in-his-warning

Comment: @MiloPrice - Hmm. Presumably it happened off-camera since it conflicts with what we see in the film

Comment: @Valorum WOWOWOWOWOWOWOW its the first time watching this video, and as i can see there are a few jedi that escaped the order 66... though i had made a question over that exact thing and i was told that only kenobi and joda escaped the massacre.... whats happening now???

Answer (score 7):

Just a bit of in-universe history for color:

It's much too long to include as a quote - but the first chapter of the new canon book "**A New Dawn**" features a pre-Order 66, youngling Kanan having a conversation with Obi-Wan. It describes that the beacon was originally intended to be a 'return to Coruscant' signal but Kanan suggested that it could be used to send any kind of message - including a 'stay away' message. Kenobi was intrigued by the idea. It is possible that he made the necessary accommodations sometime after this and thus, it was an easier task to execute than may be thought.

> Obi-Wan wasn’t looking at her. He was staring back at the beacon, too,
>   now, contemplating. “No, no,” he finally said, gesturing to the crowd
>   without turning. **“Please wait.” He scratched the back of his head and
>   turned back to the gathering. “Yes,” he said, quietly. “I suppose it
>   could be used to warn Jedi away.”**
>
> The students fairly rumbled with discussions in reaction.
>
> *Warn Jedi away?*
>
> *Jedi didn’t run! Jedi rushed toward danger!*
>
> *Jedi stood, Jedi fought!*
>
> The other Masters stepped in, beckoning to Obi-Wan. “Students,” said
>   one elder, “there’s no reason to—”
>
> **“No expected reason,” Obi-Wan said, pointing his index finger to the
>   air. He sought Caleb’s gaze. “Only what our young friend said:
>   unexpected reasons.”**
>
> A hush fell over the group. Caleb, reluctant to say anything else, let
>   another student ask what he was thinking. “What then? If you send us
>   all away, what then?”

Comment: A good find. I've taken the liberty of editing in the actual book quote.

Comment: @Valorumon your answer and on this one, i understand that after order 66 executed there were younglings even masters still alive??? you are getting me confused guys, i thought that only master yoda and obi wan escaped the massacre.... i dont understand how all this is changed now....

Comment: 1) If you *only* look at the original trilogy movies - you may be led to believe that only Yoda and Kenobi survived. 2) Even before Disney taking over, the Extended Universe of books and comics and such starting to introduce other Jedi and Force-sensitives that had survived for various reasons. 3) Once Disney took over and there is a 'new canon', the universe seems to be littered with on the run Jedi and Force sensitives and they are actively hunted and destroyed or turned when possible.

Comment: @NKCampbell It is almost like a propaganda campaign. Pre-Disney Star Wars canon was controlled by Lucas, who generally declared that all Jedi were dead after Order 66, just as the Emperor might say to quell doubt. Post-Disney we learn that there are lots of Jedi in hiding, which the New Republic might say if they wanted to undermine any remaining loyalists of the old Empire.

Comment: @hedgehog - If you watch the TV show Star Wars: Rebels, you'll see the aftermath of Order 66. Some Jedi did indeed survive.

Comment: @Valorum i really start not liking Disney....... that is a HUGE change to the scenario.......